# Transpose a large dataset

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, transpose

I have a lot of data for each User ID that needs to be organized by column rather than by row as it is currently. I have tried standard transposition methods but cannot figure this out. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
Current data set: 
    UserId  Item     Value(mL)
    1       AAA      12
    1       AAB      21
    1       AAC      31
    2       AAA      15
    2       AAB      21
    2       AAC      34
    2       AAD      16


Desired outcome: 
    UserID    AAA   AAB   AAC   AAD
    1          12    21    31
    2          15    21    34    16
```

Comment: Have you tried pivot table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With formula:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$F2,$B:$B,G$1)
```

[image]

Copy over and down.

---

As @skkakkar stated: with Pivot Table

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an excel paste option called "transpose" that will allow you to accomplish this. Select your data and copy it. Then go to the target cell and go to paste options and press "T" or click the transpose button.

EDIT:

There are other ways of solving this, as Scott has shown in his answer. If you are performing this on a large data set, my solution will be the fastest by far, but his solution is also very sleek. In addition, this won't work to only keep non-duplicate headers. You will need to do a bit of work to have this work the exact way the poster wanted.

Comment: With this method would you not need to copy each section at a time to get the numbers in the correct column?

Comment: Not from what I have tested. You will need to set up the headers but it should work just with the paste special option.

Comment: Then I am missing something, because when I use transpose on the whole data it simply rotates the data from rows to columns and does not group them like the desired outcome.  Can you post a step by step assuming the data is in A1:C8.  I would like to learn something new today.

Comment: Actually I agree with you now. I didn't see he also wanted to remove duplicates as part of the transposition. My method will not work in that case.